# Is raw POST payload available in a rest controller if it was was mapped to an object, otherwise?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have a POST endpoint, with some JSON payload that holds important data should be archived with a digest.

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

  @PostMapping(value = "/api/some")
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> postSome(@Valid @RequestBody Some some) {
    archiveAndDigest(rawJsonPostPayloadSomeHowFromCurrentContext());
    someService(some);
    return new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus>(
      ResponseStatus.builder()
...
        .build(),
        HttpStatus.CREATED
      );
  }
```

The controller endpoint is too expressive and convenient (assures content type, parses and validates input payload) to drop for raw string input, and doing all these by hand. The input payload must be preserved for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the raw JSON value instead of the deserialized object.

I can think of two ways to do it.

**1st**, which **I don't recommend**:

This way you **can't** make use of the from the Spring Validator.

*Receive the JSON as String and then turn the raw value into an object using the ObjectMapper.*

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/some")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> postSome(String rawRequest) {
        log.info("Raw value: {}", rawRequest);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Some some = mapper.readValue(rawRequest, Some.class);
        someService(some);

        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> (ResponseStatus.builder()
        ...
        .build(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**2nd**, which **I prefer**.

*Receive the object as an object (just the way you're doing) and then, getting the JSON Raw Value from the object using ObjectMapper*

This way you **can** make use of Spring Validator.

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/some")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> postSome(@Valid @RequestBody Some some) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String rawJsonValue mapper.writeValueAsString(some);
        log.info("Raw value: {}", rawJsonValue);

        someService(some);

        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> (ResponseStatus.builder()
        ...
        .build(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

I prefer the ladder, but keep in mind that any attribute sent in the JSON request that doesn't exists in your object will not be printed. This happens because the `mapper.writeValueAsString(some)` will generate a JSON based on the properties of your object.

**UPDATE**

You can define a `HttpServletRequest` as an argument to your method. That way, Spring will provide the current request and pass it in the argument.

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/some")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> postSome(@Valid @RequestBody Some some, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String rawValue = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

        System.out.println(rawValue);

        someService(some);

        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> (ResponseStatus.builder()
        ...
        .build(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i thought on similar things. the 2nd one is not the original bitstream kicked in, unfortunately. i thought even to write a filter that could intervene before object mapping and save the incoming bitstream, but I feel some unease with it.

Comment: Why feel so unease with the filter? That's one of the purposes of the filters..

Comment: I found an alternative...so mad that I forgot it when writing the answer. Answer updated.

Comment: thanks, i was not aware of the possibility to have the request as a parameter. i will dig into it. (the filter solution unease is simple, though not very well-founded. auditing the request payload is part of this special scenario. i have many other requests, i do not want to be affected.)

Comment: Great. If your question was solved, please, mark the right answer as the solution

Comment: thanks, again. it (2nd point) seems to work. (i've got no credit to upvote the answer)

Comment: unfortunately, this solution is not solution. it's simple and understandable: if you consumed the request body, it won't, be available any more. so when, as according to the proposed solution, request body was already processed into the @RequestBody object, and request.getReader() will produce end of stream.

Comment: as a final comment, i have revoked the ok from the solution, the original problem can not be resolved. you either have the raw input stream (then it can be archived, and then you have to process it on your own), or have it processed by the framework, but then the raw input bytes wo'nt be available.

Comment: Actually, I think there's a solution. Take a look at this post: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging